# managing Spring life cycle false understanding

Tags: java, spring

How can any java object after complete initialization and calling setter methods it can again perform initialization on that object

1. This is happening in spring, in first step-instantiate..and initialization(initialization completed) in
2. second step calling setter based dependency injection,then here
3. again pre initialization and post initialization(how can it perform again initialization)

Comment: Whut? Can you please rephrase your question. What is it you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: you need to post config sample, since this can happen due to multiple reasons including a `prototype` bean scope that would recreate bean on reference over and over again. more on [Spring bean scopes](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-scopes)